# "Removing" cookie isn't working

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

So one of my co-workers used the following code to "remove" the cookies from the browser. This  should work, but checking the cookies right after loading the page the cookies are still there. Is there something wrong with this code or is there a bigger problem?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie aCookie;
    string cookieName;
    int limit = Request.Cookies.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        cookieName = Request.Cookies[i].Name;
        aCookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
        aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

        if (cookieName != "Lang")
            Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
    }
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Response.Redirect("/default.aspx");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by they "are still there"? You get them on the next postback?

Comment: The cookies are still present according to chrome.

Comment: Try removing the Response.Redirect some browsers don't allow setting of cookies during redirect.

Comment: But then that defeats the purpose.... Its kinda hard to do it without that. It needs to go back to the log in page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that I've used to kill the cookie and it works for me.

```
string cookieName;
    int limit = Request.Cookies.Count;


    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        cookieName = Request.Cookies[i].Name;
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
        cookie.Value = "";
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3);
        //Only if HTTPS
        cookie.Secure = true;
        //Only if a domain is specified, and obviously, it should match the domain of the app
        cookie.Domain = "XYZ";

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Response.Redirect("/default.aspx");
```

Make sure you write the cookie to the response, which you are doing.

Comment: c# sorry... I could translate I guess. But do you have one? xD

Comment: Now in C#, the syntax was very close anyway.

Comment: Shweet. Yeah I know it is. Just op was c#. Don't want anyone confused.

Comment: The logout appears to be only when loading from the net and not localhost. Odd.

Comment: I mean the problem doesnt happen when running the site using localhost. But on the live version the problem does happen. (as in running on local machine compared to www)

Comment: Oh, you may then need to apply a domain to the cookie.  Not sure if that is the ultimate reason, but may be a reason for the effect.

Comment: It would be something like that. I think its all sorted now however.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks correct, however, I think what you are missing is posting the changes for the cookie back to the system.

You set the cookie expiration but you need to do a `Response.Cookies.Add()` with the same name to overwrite the old cookie.

Comment: `if (cookieName != "Lang")
            Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);`